# MVC Navigation Design

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

What is the best method to render some navigation hyperlinks depending on which page the user is on (I am using C# MVC 4).

I have a _layout.cshtml which looks like the following (shortened down for display purpose).

```
<body>
    @{Html.RenderAction("MainNav", "Navigation");}
    <div id="container">
        @RenderBody();
    </div>
</body>
```

If a user navigates to /Home/Index then I would want the MainNav to render hyperlinks of Home | Management

Then if a user clicks Management that will change to Home | Company | Teams | Roles and will change again if they click one of these links.

Comment: If the links vary that much depending on which page your on, then render the relevant links in the page, not the layout (otherwise you will need to pass a parameter to the `MainNav()` method and include multiple `if` statements which I suspect will be much harder to maintain)

Comment: I thought about that but then i wont be able to get the links to render where i want them to on the page as they will be stuck within the rending view but i need them within the navigation area of the website

Comment: That's what sections are for. In your layout `@RenderSection("nav", required: false)` and in the view `@section nav { // your links }`

Comment: ah, I understand now, if you add this as an answer I will upvote it and mark as answer. I do like @sam7 answer but this doesnt rely on a third party (I know that wasnt a requirement I originally asked for).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Html.RenderAction()` or `Html.Action()` would involve passing a parameter identifying your current view and using multiple `if/else` blocks to define what the partial should render. Instead you can use Razor sections to act as placeholders for specific content that can be placed anywhere in the layout.

In the layout, add `@RenderSection()`, in this case named "menu" to act as a placeholder for your menu links

```
<div id="sidebar">
  @RenderSection("menu", required: false)
</div>
<div id="container">
  @RenderBody();
</div>
```

Then in each view, add `@section menu { ... }` containing the links to display

Index.cshtml

```
// content to be displayed

@section menu {
  @Html.ActionLink("Home", .....)
  @Html.ActionLink("Management", .....)
}
```

Management.cshtml

```
// content to be displayed

@section menu {
  @Html.ActionLink("Home", .....)
  @Html.ActionLink("Company", .....)
  @Html.ActionLink("Teams", .....)
  @Html.ActionLink("Roles", .....)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The more you think about it, the more complex the problem you're describing becomes. So I tend to use a library. Even though it might seem overkill at this point, but in my experience it pays off later:

```
<body>
    @Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu()
    <div id="container">
        @RenderBody();
    </div>
</body>
```

This is all you need to do when using https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider

```
Install-Package MvcSiteMapProvider
```

Just annotate your actions like this:

```
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Menu Title")]
```

Comment: I like the look of this, do you know if you can some how add parameters to it aswell? e.g. I have 2 different types of teams and normally i would do the following... @Html.ActionLink("Team","Account", new { teamType = "Team"}) and @Html.ActionLink("Team","Account",new { teamType="Project")} I will have a read up on it also but wondered if you knew?

Comment: I wouldn't know from the top of my head. Except that there is a DynamicNodeProvider as well: https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-Sitemap-Nodes-using-IDynamicNodeProvider

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Multiple-Navigation-Paths-to-a-Single-Page